# React-native element type is invalid - export

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Very new with `react-native`, getting stuck on 'element type is invalid error'

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class SplashWalls extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      wallsJSON: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  fetchWallsJSON() {
    var url = 'https://unsplash.it/list';
    fetch(url)
      .then( response => response.json() )
      .then( jsonData => {
        console.log(jsonData);

        this.setState({isLoading: false}); //update isLoading
      })
    .catch( error => console.log('Fetch error ' + error) );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchWallsJSON();
  }

  render() {
    var {isLoading} = this.state;
    if(isLoading)
      return this.renderLoadingMessage();
    else
      return this.renderResults();
  }

  renderLoadingMessage() {
    return (

   <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicatorIOS
          animating={true}
          color={'#fff'}
          size={'small'}
          style={{margin: 15}} />
          <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Contacting Unsplash</Text>

   </View>
    );
  }

  renderResults() {
    return (

   <View>
        <Text>
          Data loaded
        </Text>

   </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loadingContainer: {
      flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SplashWalls', () => SplashWalls);
```

Error states:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in.
>
> Check the Render method of 'SplashWalls'.

Any ideas?

Comment: try binding your render methods in the constructor: `this. renderLoadingMessage = this. renderLoadingMessage.bind(this)`, same for the second method.

Comment: whats the name of your project folder? SplashWalls only ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your

```
<ActivityIndicatorIOS />
```

This component is deprecated already and has to be replaced with

```
<ActivityIndicator>
```

more information can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/activityindicator.html

To continue with [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/04/the-beauty-of-react-native-building-your-first-ios-app-with-javascript-part-1/) tutorial you have to make the following changes:

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
```

and

```
renderLoadingMessage () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <ActivityIndicator
          animating={true}
          color={'#fff'}
          size={'small'} 
          style={{margin: 15}} />
        <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>Contacting Unsplash</Text>
      </View>
   )
 }
```